Existence of a Bessel process via Girsanov Transform
currently I am interested in Bessel processes of dimension $d=3$, i.e. we are interested in the solution of SDE given as follows
$$
dX_t = 1/X_t dt + dB_t \quad X_0 = x > 0,
$$
where $B_t$ is Brownian motion. I already know that via Ito's formula one can prove that $X_t = \|B_t\|^{3}$, where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the euclidean norm, solves this SDE but I am interested in obtaining a weak solution of this SDE via Girsanov's theorem. Thus one should have the following strategy:

Start with a Brownian motion $X$ on some filtration probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_t,P)$.
Using Girsanov's theorem if we "cleverly" choose a predictable coordinate process $(a_t)_{t \geq 0}$  on $C[0,\infty)$ such that $\int a^2_s ds < \infty$ then by considering the stochastic exponential $Z:=\mathcal{E}\left(\int a(X) dX \right)$ and assuming that $E[Z_{\infty}]=1$ we know that

--> The coordinate process is given by $dQ/dP := Z_{\infty}$ and
--> That under the probability measure $Q$ we know that
$$
W := X-X_0 - \int a_s ds,
$$
is a $(\mathcal{F}_t,Q)$ Brownian motion and rearranging yields a weak solution to the Bessel process SDE that is given by
$$
X = W + X_0 + \int a_s ds.
$$
Some ideas:
--> Since we want the Bessel process to start from $x>0$, we are chosing a $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_t,P)$ Brownian motion that starts from $x_0$.
--> Since the "drift"-term in the Bessel SDE is given by $\int a_s ds$, it seems that we need to choose $a_s(X) = 1/X_s$ as our predictable process.
--> This raises the issue that since $X$ as Brownian motion hits zero infinitly often in any fixed interval $[0,\epsilon)$ we need to introduce a stopping time as follows: Fix $0<\epsilon<x$ and $R>0$ large enough then consider the stopping time $\tau_{\epsilon,R} = \inf\{t \geq 0 : B_t \in (\epsilon,R)^c\}$, we then apply the Girsanov's theorem by considering the stopped Brownian motion $X_{t \wedge \tau_{\epsilon,R}}$.
Question: I am not sure whether the process $a_t(X) = X_{t \wedge \tau_{R,\epsilon}}$ is the correct predictable process to choose. In some other notes for example here people are considering
the following Radon-Nikodym derivative given by
$$
\frac{d \hat{P}_{\epsilon,R,t}}{dP} = N_{t \wedge \tau_{\epsilon,R}},
$$
where
$$
N_t = \left(\frac{X_t}{X_0}\right)^{a} \; \exp\left(-\frac{(a-1)a}{2} \int^{t}_0 \frac{ds}{X^2_s}\right) \quad t < \tau,
$$
however here I cannot see the link to my stochastic exponential $\mathcal{E}\left(\int a(X) dX\right)$.
